# Visual studio cshtml file changes don't take place until I rebuild/rerun

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

Visual studio cshtml file changes don't take place until I rebuild/rerun.

Meaning, when I run my MVC website (run with or without debugging), then I make a cshtml file change and save, then reload the website, the changes don't take effect. I tried all sorts of hard reloads/cache clearing. The problem seemed to be with visual studio rather than the browser.

First time it's ever happened in 6 years and it lasted a good week (vs2015 constantly closed/opened, computer restarted many times).

Comment: I am having the same issue with visual studio 2017.  Have to rebuild even if I change the cshtml file.  If I hit F5 to refresh, it would error.

Answer (score 0):

Never figured out the root cause, however I started Visual Studio 2015 in safe mode and it seemed to solve the problem (for now). I didn't even stay in safe mode, I came out into the normal mode and the problem hasn't come back. To run VS2015 in safe mode, make a shortcut to the devenv.exe and add "/safemode" at the end:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /safemode
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/11/15/visual-studio-safe-mode/